# Android manifest config for smartphone only, Sony Xperia Z, HTC One and Samsung Galaxy S4 missing on google play

Tags: android-manifest, google-play

I've an android app on the google play, which is only compatible for smartphone (i'm working on the tablet adaptation).

I've set up this configuration in my AndroidManifest.xml to exclude the tablets: (i exclude x-large)

```
<supports-screens
android:largeScreens="true"
android:normalScreens="true"
android:smallScreens="true"
android:resizeable="true"
android:anyDensity="true"
/>
```

It works fine, but now the new smartphones Sony Xperia Z, HTC One and Samsung Galaxy S4 are not compatible. And if i try my app the display is just fine on these devices

I can't find if theses models are considered as "x-large" screen.

Anyone facing this problem?

Thanks

Thibault

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Adding the following line will enable support for large phones with xxhdpi displays:

```
<screen android:screenSize="large" android:screenDensity="480" />
```

Comment: Thanks a lot, but actually there is this line to add as well: <screen android:screenSize="normal" android:screenDensity="480" /> , Google should really document that !!!

Answer (score 0):

Some smart phones have very large screens as well. Try `android:xlargeScreens="true"` as well.

Comment: Of course it will work, but i will make the tablets compatible as well.

I'm looking for a solution to include theses smartphone but stil exclude the tablets.

Comment: I guess the questions you have to ask yourself are a) why don't you want it to work on a tablet, and b) what is it about tablets that make you want to exclude them?  If you can answer b), then that might tell you want to put in your manifest.

Comment: a) because my app display is not nice on tablet , bad user experience will trigger bad comments (i'm working on a tablet version)

b) same answer, i've nothing against tablet, my app is just not ready yet for them, but it's ready for S4, HTC One X and Sony Xperia Z