# Android Screen support for Samsung S4 & HTC ONE

Tags: android, screen

I've been browing the site for an answer, I followed this: [Android manifest config for smartphone only, Sony Xperia Z, HTC One and Samsung Galaxy S4 missing on google play](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16326656/android-manifest-config-for-smartphone-only-sony-xperia-z-htc-one-and-samsung)

And yet, google Play does not show Samsung S4 & HTC One as supported by my app

in my manifest:

```
<uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="8" android:targetSdkVersion="16"/> 

<compatible-screens>
    <screen android:screenDensity="mdpi" android:screenSize="normal"/>
    <screen android:screenDensity="hdpi" android:screenSize="normal"/>
    <screen android:screenDensity="xhdpi" android:screenSize="normal"/>
    <screen android:screenDensity="mdpi" android:screenSize="large"/>
    <screen android:screenDensity="hdpi" android:screenSize="large"/>
    <screen android:screenDensity="xhdpi" android:screenSize="large"/>
    <screen android:screenDensity="mdpi" android:screenSize="xlarge"/>
    <screen android:screenDensity="hdpi" android:screenSize="xlarge"/>
    <screen android:screenDensity="xhdpi" android:screenSize="xlarge"/>
    <screen android:screenSize="normal" android:screenDensity="213"/>
    <screen android:screenSize="large" android:screenDensity="213"/>
    <screen android:screenSize="xlarge" android:screenDensity="213"/>
    <screen android:screenDensity="480" android:screenSize="normal" />
    <screen android:screenDensity="480" android:screenSize="large" />
    <screen android:screenDensity="480" android:screenSize="xlarge" />

</compatible-screens>

    <supports-screens android:resizeable="true"
              android:smallScreens="false"
              android:normalScreens="true"
              android:largeScreens="true"
              android:xlargeScreens="true"
              android:anyDensity="true"

              />

<uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.camera" android:required="false"/>
```

Any clue as to what is going on? any help is appreciated

Comment: Refer to both of these links. 

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19380811/android-manifest-that-will-support-galaxy-s4-htc-one

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17673640/android-my-app-is-not-supporting-galxy-s-4

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should not use compatible-screens. Look in following link might help http://developer.sonymobile.com/2013/03/07/make-sure-your-app-does-not-exclude-xxhdpi-screens/

Comment: just removed compatible-screen and left supports-screens, uploaded, still missing! heeeeelp!