# Android manifest that will support Galaxy S4, HTC One

Tags: android, android-manifest, manifest, galaxy, htc-android

Im trying to create Android manifest that *Google Play* will show to Samsung Galaxy S4, HTC One and so on since current one doesn't list those in compatible devices list.

I did search Stack Overflow, but all advices here didn't help me. Below is manifest that I am using for our app...

We tried also to remove complete `<compatible-screens>` and leave only `<support-screens>` but still no-go...

Thanks in advance

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
package="com.application.testapp"
android:versionCode="4"
android:versionName="1.01c"
android:installLocation="auto" >
<uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="8"  android:targetSdkVersion="17"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE"/>
<supports-screens 
android:anyDensity="true" 
android:largeScreens="true"
android:normalScreens="true" 
android:smallScreens="true"
android:xlargeScreens="true" 
android:resizeable="true" /> 
<compatible-screens>
<!-- all small size screens -->
<screen android:screenSize="small" android:screenDensity="ldpi" />
<screen android:screenSize="small" android:screenDensity="mdpi" />
<screen android:screenSize="small" android:screenDensity="hdpi" />
<screen android:screenSize="small" android:screenDensity="xhdpi" />
<screen android:screenSize="small" android:screenDensity="480" />
<!-- all normal size screens -->
<screen android:screenSize="normal" android:screenDensity="ldpi" />
<screen android:screenSize="normal" android:screenDensity="mdpi" />
<screen android:screenSize="normal" android:screenDensity="hdpi" />
<screen android:screenSize="normal" android:screenDensity="xhdpi" />
<screen android:screenSize="normal" android:screenDensity="480" />
<!-- all large size screens -->
<screen android:screenSize="large" android:screenDensity="ldpi" />
<screen android:screenSize="large" android:screenDensity="mdpi" />
<screen android:screenSize="large" android:screenDensity="hdpi" />
<screen android:screenSize="large" android:screenDensity="xhdpi" />
<screen android:screenSize="large" android:screenDensity="480" />
<!-- all xlarge size screens -->
<screen android:screenSize="xlarge" android:screenDensity="ldpi" />
<screen android:screenSize="xlarge" android:screenDensity="mdpi" />
<screen android:screenSize="xlarge" android:screenDensity="hdpi" />
<screen android:screenSize="xlarge" android:screenDensity="xhdpi" />
<screen android:screenSize="xlarge" android:screenDensity="480" />
</compatible-screens>
<application
android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
android:label="@string/app_name" android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Light">
<uses-library android:name="com.google.android.maps"/> 
<activity 
android:name=".Main"
android:label="@string/app_name" android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Light.NoTitleBar" android:screenOrientation="portrait">
<intent-filter>
<action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
<category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
</intent-filter>
</activity>
<activity android:name=".SplashScreen" android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Light.NoTitleBar.Fullscreen" android:screenOrientation="portrait">
<intent-filter>
<action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN"></action>
<category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER"></category>
</intent-filter>
</activity>
<activity android:name=".ActivityProducst" android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Light.NoTitleBar" android:screenOrientation="portrait"/>
<activity android:name=".ActivityDetails" android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Light.NoTitleBar" android:screenOrientation="portrait"/>
<activity android:name=".ActivityNews" android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Light.NoTitleBar" android:screenOrientation="portrait"/>
<activity android:name=".ActivityImage" android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Light.NoTitleBar" android:screenOrientation="portrait"/>
<activity android:name=".ActivityAbout" android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Light.NoTitleBar" android:screenOrientation="portrait"/>
</application>
</manifest>
```

Comment: What you want exactly?? Sorry, but can't get your problem.

Comment: This manifest, when uploaded to google play dont include in supported list of devices Samsung S4, Htc One, Sony Experia and similar latest devices... And I have no clue why. So what exactly I need to put in manifest so that when I upload it on Google Play, SGS4, HTC One will be listed as supported...

Comment: Do you need to use supports-screens and compatible-screens for any other reason? Otherwise you don't have to do anything and all devices will be supported.

Comment: Not really, so you suggest to remove support-screens and compatible screens alltogether?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

in my app i use this manifest (i changed the package and activity names):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest 
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.blabla"
    android:versionCode="8"
    android:versionName="1.6">

    <uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="7" 
              android:targetSdkVersion="18"/>

    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>

    <application 
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher" 
        android:label="@string/app_name">

        <activity
            android:label="@string/app_name"
            android:name="com.blabla.Activity"
            android:configChanges="orientation" >

            <intent-filter >
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>

        </activity>

        <activity
            android:label="@string/app_name"
            android:name="com.blabla.Optionen" >
        </activity>

    </application>
</manifest>
```

And the Google Play store says that it is compatible with > 4000 devices, HTC One an SGS4 are included.

I hope i understand your question right.

Comment: Actually this worked... removed all screen settings in manifest, and increased target version to 18

Answer (score 0):

I hope you are looking for this,

Change this in `Manifest`

```
<supports-screens
    android:anyDensity="true"
    android:largeScreens="true"
    android:normalScreens="true"
    android:smallScreens="true"
    android:xlargeScreens="true"        
/>
```

Only, this won't help. You want different image sizes, different layouts for different resolutions.

**Edit:**

http://developer.android.com/guide/practices/screens_support.html

You have to add differnt folder for different layout in res folder --> hdpi,mdpi,ldpi and for large screens you xhdpi(for Tablet) and large-hdpi or xlarge (for NXzoom). and also set Images and textsize different in different layout as per screensize.

Comment: Care to elaborate? I have `<supports-screens 
android:anyDensity="true" 
android:largeScreens="true"
android:normalScreens="true" 
android:smallScreens="true"
android:xlargeScreens="true" 
android:resizeable="true" /> ` in manifest, you suggest to remove anything that you didnt stated above?

Comment: Do this also, `android:anyDensity="false"`

Answer (score 0):

You can do this configurations on Android Developer Console, which will publish the app to only the devices you select.

Comment: No, I can select which devices to EXCLUDE, and I want to actually Include SGS4, HTC One and so on...

Comment: exclude everyone but those?

Comment: how about targetting devices with version higher than 4.0.4 or 4.1 or whatever?