# Google play This app is incompatible with all of your devices

Tags: android

I developed a webview based android app , tested it - worked fine , uploaded to Google Play , and when I go to see the app I get This app is incompatible with all of your devices - I had wildfire and now I have Media Pad 7 inch tablet.
This is my manifest file

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.compensatemeonline.uscompaniesdb"
    android:versionCode="4"
    android:versionName="1.3" >

    <supports-screens>
    android:largeScreens="true"
    android:normalScreens="true"
    android:smallScreens="true"
    android:xlargeScreens="true" 
    android:anyDensity="true"
    </supports-screens>

    <uses-sdk
        android:minSdkVersion="4"
        android:targetSdkVersion="17" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
        <activity
            android:name="com.compensatemeonline.uscompaniesdb.MainActivity"
            android:label="@string/app_name" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
    </application>

</manifest>
```

and this is my application...
https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.compensatemeonline.uscompaniesdb&hl=en
[image]

Comment: Does it say why it's incompatible with all of your devices? Maybe you've restricted it in the vendor portal.

Comment: It says it can not be installed on my devices - i Know it can , it is a basic webview website application .I have put no restriction nor any filters while publishing , in the list of phones that can use my app are my phone types ! There are no any filters for countries and from my country I can buy the app.

Comment: I plugged in your play-url and it says the app can be installed on all my devices (~15) except my GoogleTV. How many supported devices does the developer console show?

Comment: Google play say  Supported devices
4156

Comment: Try to delete ALL of "supports-screens" from the manifest and then install again. You can also look here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19380811/android-manifest-that-will-support-galaxy-s4-htc-one/19381223#19381223

Comment: While I don't think supports-screens is the issue, the syntax for that element is wrong. Those are supposed to be attributes of the tag, not its contents.

Comment: You may be right about supports-screens syntax , if that is so how did it compile with no errors!?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seams that the problem is in fact that in my country Serbia , payed apps can be bought only by using some phones that have installed new versions of Google Play app . This seems to be the problem since other users abroad using same types of phones are allowed to use the app.